# Brighten and unify the background of a scanned image

Tags: image-editing, scanning

My girlfriend has scanned a few comics images, drawn with pencil. She wants to publish them on the web, but the different grayscale shadows of the paper are still evident in the image.

I would like to make all the light gray colors transferred into white background, using a simple method and open source software.

Any ideas?

Comment: so you basically want rudimentary image editing software.  What OS do you use?

Comment: I am platform independent, my girlfriend is an XP user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) you can achieve it like this:

```
convert source.jpeg -white-threshold 75% target.jpeg
```

All pixels in the source image with a brightness level of 75% or higher will be set to white in the target image. Just play with the threshold value until you get something that works well. It could be a problem if parts of the drawing comes out brighter than the paper in your scans, but that shouldn't normally be the case.

Comment: That's great. I'll do it and write back about the results.

Comment: That worked just fine for me.

Comment: Works like a charm in my situation :)